# Hide columns if cell has a given value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to hide some columns if A1 changes but I am afraid that the function Worksheet_Change does not work.

I have the following code but if I change A1 nothing happens.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "A1" Then

        Call hideColumns()
        '
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There are some extra arguments in the Address method, that will allow you to strip the locking of cell/row i.e. the $'s  you could also say if `target.column*target.row=1`

Comment: What you *really* need to learn is how to ***debug*** your code. Something as simple as `Debug.Print Target.Address` would have shown you that `.Address` returns a string containing the absolute cell reference.

Comment: Do you have a good guide to learn how to debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to

```
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
```

or maybe use (my favorite):

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: LOL - As soon as I see "my favorite" (especially with the American spelling) I want to add the word "Martian" after it.  (I'm showing my age again - it was one of my favourite TV shows when I was young.)

Comment: @YowE3K :) I like to trap the `Worksheet_Change` event that way, it seems to me the most reliable and flexible (especially if you define a second Range to Trap)

Comment: @ShaiRado, technically the two aren't doing the same thing. The first will return `True` when just A1 is changed whereas the second returns `True` when any number of cells are changed at the same time, so long as A1 is in that range. Might be relevant to OP.

Answer (score 0):

To hide *Columns Columns("B").EntireColumn.Hidden = False / True* Or 
To hide Rows *Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = False / True*

*Example*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = 0

    If Not Intersect(Target, ([A1])) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Else
            Columns("D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = 1
End Sub
```

> <sub>*[Range.Hidden Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834657.aspx)* *Returns or sets a Variant value that indicates if the rows or columns are hidden, Set property to True to hide a row or column. The specified range must span an entire column or row.*</sub>
>
> ---
>
> <sub>*[Application.EnableEvents Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821508.aspx)* *EnableEvents Application Property in Excel VBA is used to enable events for the specified object. It has Boolean value that is either True or False.*</sub>

Comment: For rows is the same? Just substituting "Columns" with "Rows"?

Comment: @Simons123 For Row 2 = `Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = False or True`

Comment: @Simons123 consider up voting in the answer was helpful